# Is there some simple way display any image from folder in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, directory, display, any

I was googling but without luck, I found some stackoverflow with making list of images, randomizing it etc but it seems really long process of what I want and I'm thinking If there is some simpler way of doing this.

What I want is, instead of specifying images/image3.jpg. Can I say to display image from a folder called "bluethemedimages" ? - So it will display randomly/any image from this folder. What i want to create is to have 4 different themes, Blue, Yellow, Green, Grey (Each theme will have different coloured images) so later on when the user presses "blue" button it will display any random image from the "bluethemedimages" folder. Below is example of my page and box decoration with the image.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        //color: Colors.transparent,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/image3.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
```

Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that I used in my application

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("randomimage"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),)))
    onclick(){
       var _random = new Random();
       setstate((){
            randomimage="Bluethemedimage/$(_random.nextInt(no_of_pictures)+1)"}}
```

name your pictures as 1.png,2.png,3.png and so on

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. That's actually something I been looking for.